# how to set system properties in C#

Tags: c#

how can i set system properties in C#.

In java i can use:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/path/to/where/you/ve/put/chromedriver.exe");
```

how to do this in C#?

Comment: What system properties?  Those are **Java** system properties.

Comment: I don't imagine there is an equivalent

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.chrome.driver",@"/path/to/where/you/ve/put/chromedriver.exe")`
-[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

There's no equivalent of "system properties" in C#. They're a Java-specific concept. (They're not really *system* properties in Java - they're JVM-wide-properties, some of which are derived from system environment variables etc.)

You should look in the WebDriver documentation for how to set this for the .NET version.

EDIT: Just to clarify, `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` *could* be used in a similar way, but it tends not to be in my experience.

Comment: I believe `System.Environment` is a good an equivalent. What do you think?

Comment: @manojlds: Well, it's not really the same... and typically not *used* in the same way. Quite a few Java libraries use system properties (although I'm not a fan of that) - I can't remember seeing any .NET ones which do...

Answer (score 2):

[`System.Environment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) will provide you some "properties" but this is a Java specific concept which will not have any direct equivalent in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start Selenium Server with the following option: **Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\path\to\your\chromedriver.exe**

Like this:
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\path\to\your\chromedriver.exe

Comment: Huh? The question asks for csharp, not java

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this thread is really old, but if you ended up on this page, an alternative solution is to add chromedriver.exe to your project, set Build Action to "Content" and set Copy to Output Directory to "Copy if newer".  Then you can skip setting the environment variable.

The drawback to this solution is that you'll end up with multiple copies of a 5 MB file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Environment class, you could set some of the properties there.