# selenium ie webdriver without my user profile

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium-webdriver

i need to implement selenium Ie `WebDriver` in a way that it will be a new internet explorer.

or it will not access my user account, 
meanning it will not have aceess to cookies nor temporary internet files nor history

am i mistaking that when using `InternetExplorerDriver`
it is using the information of my windows account such history etc'?

Comment: @user1177636 i have found an alternative to `System.SetProperty` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180450/how-to-set-system-properties-in-c-sharp   though i need to find how to initialise webdriver with capablilities as i said in this post and also the ignore zoom property seems that its ither accepting string=driver file location or options ... which i didnot understand

Answer (score 0):

this is what i could find , still need to get options for staring fresh IE9 session 
but solved issue with how to initialise properly.

```
    public IWebDriver WebDriver;

    var ieDir = Path.Combine(path, "bin");
    var opts = new InternetExplorerOptions();
    opts.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;

    if (counter < 1) //or in most other cases - (WebDriver==null)
    {
        CleanBr(); // found a solution to programatically delete Browser history 
        // so i still need to find the resolution for options with starting fresh IE profile
        // an IE driver without a user data... 

        WebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieDir, opts);
    }
    INavigation nav = WebDriver.Navigate();
    nav.GoToUrl(url);
```